# C# How to return string values from a loop as list items

Tags: c#, console-application

I have an application for a pizza shop order system, which asks a customer to input how many pizzas they would like to order, and based on the quantity, select their pizza base and topping options. I want to be able to list the crust and topping values as a string, for each individual pizza at the bottom of the program within the invoice section.

Does anyone know how I can pass through the string values of each individual pizza into the invoice section at the bottom?

```
// Ask user for pizza order details
            //crust selection
            qtyPizzas = numPizzas();
            for (loop = 1; loop <= qtyPizzas; loop++)
            {
                crustOption = selectCrust();
                crustPrice = crustCost(crustOption);
                if (crustOption == 1)
                {
                    crustString = "thin crust";
                }
                else
                {
                    crustString = "deep pan";
                }
                //topping selection
                toppingOption = selectTopping();
                toppingPrice = toppingCost(toppingOption);
                if (toppingOption == 1)
                {
                    toppingString = "ham";
                }
                else if (toppingOption == 2)
                {
                    toppingString = "mushrooms";
                }
                else if (toppingOption == 3)
                {
                    toppingString = "mediterranean vegetables";
                }
                else if (toppingOption == 4)
                {
                    toppingString = "extra cheese";
                }
                unitPrice = crustPrice + toppingPrice;
                totalPizzaCost = totalPizzaCost + unitPrice;
                Console.WriteLine("- Pizza #" + loop + ": " + crustString + " with " + toppingString + " (£" + unitPrice + ")");
                pizzaSelection = Convert.ToString(crustString + " " + toppingString);
            }

            Console.Write("pizza delivery? (y/n): ");
            deliveryOption = Console.ReadLine();

            // Calculate delivery cost based on distance
            if (deliveryOption == "y")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter delivery distance in miles: ");
                deliveryDistance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (deliveryDistance <= 2)
                {
                    deliveryCost += 0;
                }
                else if (deliveryDistance <= 5)
                {
                    deliveryCost += 3.00;
                }
                else if (deliveryDistance <= 8)
                {
                    deliveryCost += 5.00;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we do not deliver that far.");
                }
            }


            // calculate total cost
            vat = (totalPizzaCost + deliveryCost) * (100 + 20) / 100;
            orderVAT = vat - totalPizzaCost - deliveryCost;

            // Output the invoice
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("INVOICE");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Customer ID: " + customerID);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Pizzas:");

            for (int i = 1; i <= qtyPizzas; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pizza # " + i + ": " + pizzaSelection);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("  Total pizza costs: " + totalPizzaCost.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("  Delivery cost: " + deliveryCost.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("  VAT: " + orderVAT.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("  Grand total (incl. VAT): " + vat.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

I tried doing this using a for loop in the invoice section, and it will display the correct number of pizzas that the customer has specified to order, but it only shows the last crust and topping value in each of the strings.

Comment: I believe this lesson was intended to teach you (at least in part) about arrays (or lists). When you get the input for the pizzas, you're writing them to the console but you don't retain them for later (`pizzaSelection` is overwritten each time). A direct answer to this question would defeat the purpose of it being an assignment about arrays. You should read about arrays and then try to figure out how to employ them in this application. If you have a specific question about a problem with how you've used arrays, you could ask it and you wouldn't be defeating the assignment.

Comment: Review note / important advice: If you ever find yourself typing "Convert.", ***stop***. It's almost certainly the wrong thing. Learn--no--internalize that up front. In this case, concatenating strings to create a new string *and then* passing that to `Convert.ToString` is pointless; it's already a string so it doesn't need to be converted. As for any other `Convert` methods, things like `Convert.ToInt32` should be `int.TryParse`, and so on. Don't get in the habit of relying on `Convert`; it's like performing surgery with a sledge hammer.

Comment: Learn about [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) and apply that. Consider using some index cards to represent variables and move them around running the program on a table. For example, look at your loop: you write out the variable `pizzaSelection` each time through, but it never changes inside the loop, so it will always write the same value.

Comment: Given that the code as presented is requesting the number of pizzas at the start and then looping exactly that many times, the instructor is probably looking for arrays at this point.  Assignments that are okay to use `List<T>` usually prompt "anything else?" and loop or break depending on the answer.